# Unable to use newly created Stack Exchange OpenID account

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I've created a new Stack Exchange OpenID account (since it's not possible to change the e-mail address associated to an OpenID account).

When I tried to click on the link in the e-mail address validation message I got the "Ooops something went wrong" faceplanted panda. Trying to click the validation link again later lead to the "account already validated" page.

When I try to log-in with the new account, either directly or when linking it to my Stack Exchange profile, I again get the faceplanted panda.

Once — and only once — I got a different error message, something like "missing authentication parameter" (I don't remember the wording exactly and I never got it again).

I'm able to log-in correctly at https://openid.stackexchange.com/ but nowhere else.

I always close the browser and clean local data (cookies & co.) between tries.

Am I doing something wrong?

My new account ID is `e093279f-73bd-4d96-86a0-a52e0176e897`.

Comment: Maybe you were logged in with your existing account. Try to copy the link from the email and paste it in Incognito/Private mode of the browser and see what happens.

Comment: @ShadowWizard despite the error the new account seems to have been validated: if I try to use again the link I get the "Account already confirmed — This account has already been created, log in to begin using it." message. I'm able to log-in at https://openid.stackexchange.com/ without issue and there the account seems to be OK.

Comment: But if you try to access SE sites with it, what happens?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I get the faceplanted panda with the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" message error page. See http://i.stack.imgur.com/UAFNE.png

Comment: Weird, fear only a dev can look into it deeper. :/

Comment: I'm really sorry for the long delay in response here. I looked over your accounts and it looks like everything seems to be working now. Is that correct? If not, let me know roughly the date and time of your last login attempt that errored out and I'll keep digging. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamLear yes, now the new account is working correctly, it has already been merged with the old one too, thanks.

Comment: @Albireo Glad to hear it. Thanks.